# I keep getting the error 'Exception: You do not have permission to call SpreadsheetApp.openById.'

Tags: google-apps-script, file-permissions

I'm trying to create a Macro that will export a sheet from a master spreadsheet to another spreadsheet. I keep getting this error even though I'm the owner of both spreadsheets. Here is my code:

```
function exportAndRenameSheet() {
// Source spreadsheet details
var sourceSpreadsheetId = 'XXXXXXXX';
var sourceSheetName = 'XXXXXX';  // Replace with the name of the source sheet

// Target spreadsheet details
var targetSpreadsheetId = 'XXXXXXXXXXX';
var targetSheetNamePrefix = 'Exported_';  // Prefix for the new sheet name

// Open the source spreadsheet
var sourceSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sourceSpreadsheetId);

// Get the source sheet
var sourceSheet = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sourceSheetName);

if (!sourceSheet) {
Logger.log('Source sheet not found.');
return;
}

// Copy the source sheet to a temporary sheet
var tempSheet = sourceSheet.copyTo(sourceSpreadsheet);`your text`

// Get the date for renaming the sheet
var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), 'yyyy-MM-dd');

// Rename the temporary sheet with the desired prefix and date
tempSheet.setName(targetSheetNamePrefix + formattedDate);

// Open the target spreadsheet
var targetSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(targetSpreadsheetId);

// Check if the sheet with the same name already exists in the target spreadsheet
var existingSheet = targetSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(tempSheet.getName());

// If the sheet exists, delete it before copying the new sheet
if (existingSheet) {
  targetSpreadsheet.deleteSheet(existingSheet);
}

// Copy the temporary sheet to the target spreadsheet
var newSheet = tempSheet.copyTo(targetSpreadsheet);

// Delete the temporary sheet from the source spreadsheet
sourceSpreadsheet.deleteSheet(tempSheet);

Logger.log('Sheet exported and renamed successfully.');
}
```

I've turned on Google App Scripts API, I've double checked my permissions on both Sheets (even though I'm the owner). I've run macros before where Google asked me to grant permissions for access, but this one hasn't asked. Thanks in advance!`

Comment: Are both spreadsheets in the same account? If not have you shared them?

Comment: I own both sheets, and I created both, so they're under the same account.

Comment: You have some operations in your code that don't make sense to me so I just wrote one myself because I don't like to debug others work.

Comment: If you are calling this from a simple trigger then that's a problem.

Answer (score 0):

This exports a sheet from one spreadsheet to another and renames it.

```
function exportAndRenameSheet() {
  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(gobj.globals.test1id);
  var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(gobj.globals.test2id);
  var ssh = sss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  if (!ssh) {
    Logger.log('Source sheet not found.');
    return;
  }
  var tsh = ssh.copyTo(tss); 
  var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
  tsh.setName('Exported_' + formattedDate);
  Logger.log('Sheet exported and renamed successfully.');
}
```

Comment: This is much cleaner, thank you! Unfortately, it's still giving me the permissions error. Another post mentions fixing this issue with an installable trigger?

Comment: You never mentioned anything about a  trigger. What kind of trigger are you using and how are you using it?

Comment: I'm not using a trigger, just saying that I've seen using a trigger as a fix for this particular error.

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out. Thank you again, I really appreciate you taking the time to help me!